# Zero value for funcs

Tags: go, functional-programming

Given a struct:

```
type foo struct {
  bar func(int) int
}
```

when I `var x foo`

what is the initial value of `x.bar` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_types) :

> The value of an uninitialized variable of function type is nil.

Comment: Doh! for some reason googling didn't pop up the docs and I never thought to look.  Thanks.  Bookmarking so I don't ask stupid obvious questions again.

Comment: @MushinNoShin: or you could simply printf the value

Comment: @MushinNoShin At least now this should turn in in Google for other users ;)

Comment: @dystroy and hopefully they'll see just how clear, readable and accessible the docs are :D

Comment: @StuartLC: I see it now ;) dystroy just beat him to the answer on his own question.